# Create root XML node with more than 1 namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, backbone.js, namespaces

I am working with Backbone.js with Restful services. Have to post XML. 
I want to add more than 1 namespace

Current JS code is like,

```
var nsp = "xmlns='http://services.xyz/xmlschema/common'";
var nsp2 = "xmlns:ns2='http://services.xyz/xmlschema/subscription'";

var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(nsp, "ns2:subscription", "");
```

But i expect XML root node is like,

```
<ns2:subscription xmlns='http://services.xyz/xmlschema/common' 
xmlns:ns2='http://services.xyz/xmlschema/subscription'>..</ns2:subscription>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element node can have only a single namespace, but multiple namespace definitions. You can add them as attribute nodes in the xmlns namespace. This is only needed if the namespace is not used by the element node or one of its attribute nodes.

```js
var xmlns = {
    common : "http://services.xyz/xmlschema/common",
    xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/",
    ns2 : "http://services.xyz/xmlschema/subscription",
    ns3 : "urn:ns3"
};

var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('', '', null);
// create node in namespace (adds namespace definition)
var node = dom.appendChild(dom.createElementNS(xmlns.ns2, 'ns2:subscription'));
// default namespace - simple xmlns attribute
node.setAttribute('xmlns', xmlns.common);
// other namespace - attribute in xmlns namespace
node.setAttributeNS(xmlns.xmlns, 'xmlns:ns3', xmlns.ns3);

document.getElementById('demo').textContent = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(dom);
```

```html
<textarea id="demo" style="width: 100%; height: 5em;"></textarea>
```